# How to manually raise an event by supplying X, Y and Windowhandle parameters?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

We are working on a module in which I gave the xpos, ypos, windowhandle.
Now what I want to do is I want to raise the event for the corresponding input on `(xpos, ypos, windowhandle)`.

For example:

The input given is to select a file means it will select a file automatically through my module.

```
00010086 PWM_LBUTTONDBCLK fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:273yPos:354
```

The event will look like the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo code.. You can modify to suit your need...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Form1 : Form
{
   [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

   public Form1()
   {
   }

   public void DoMouseClick()
   {
      //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
   }

  //...other code needed for the application
}
```

Comment: thru code i need to open file . for which i can give xpos, ypos.... is it possible....

Comment: S, You can read and pass the function parameters to above mouseevent function, to generate the mouse event from user32.dll. Even you can send keystrokes as given in 
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx